# Get the closest element with class

Tags: jquery, closest

I have this HTML code:

```
<div class="editor-field">
            <span class="_placeholder focused">  <label for="Name">Name</label></span>
            <input type="text" value="" name="Name" id="Name" data-val-required="Please enter name" data-val="true" class="contactInput valid">
            <span data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="Name" class="field-validation-valid"></span>
        </div>
```

I try to get the span with class 'placeholder' on keypress the input with class contactInput.
This is what I tried with no success

```
 $(".contactInput").keydown(function (e) {
    var length = $(this).val().length;

    var placeholder = $(this).prev('_placeholder');

    if (length == 0) {

        placeholder.fadeIn();
    } else {

        placeholder.fadeOut();
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Missing `.` in your [**class selector**](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)

```
var placeholder = $(this).prev('._placeholder');
//..............................^...............
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a `.` before the class name:

```
var placeholder = $(this).prev('._placeholder');
                           // --^
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var placeholder = $(this).closest('div').find('._placeholder');
```